# The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to copy and paste the numbers included in column 2 and 3 in the line if the first 4 digits of the string in column 1 in line n+1 is equal to the first 4 digits of the string line n

[exemple of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPyei.png)

```
var sh1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
vs = sh1.getRange('A1:C' +sh1.getLastRow()).getValues();
var result = []


for (i=0; i < vs.length; i++){

 if ( vs[i][0].toString().substring(0,4) == vs[i+1][0].toString().substring(0,4)){
  var a = vs[i][1];
  var b = vs[i][2];
  result.push([[a], [b]]); 
 }

 if( result.length > 0 ) {
  sh1.getRange(i+1,2,1,2).setValues(result)
 }
```

I obtain:
The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 2 but the range has 1.

Comment: `result.push([a, b])` ?

Comment: No, it is the same..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function pushif() {
  var sh1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  vs = sh1.getRange('A1:C' + sh1.getLastRow()).getValues();
  for (i = 0; i < vs.length - 1; i++) {
    if (vs[i][0].slice(0, 4) != vs[i + 1][0].slice(0, 4)) {
      vs[i][1] = '';
      vs[i][2] = '';
    }
  }
    sh1.getRange(1, 1, vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

Your stated question doesn't really have anything to do with your question.

Comment: It doesn't work, the first numbers in column 2 and 3 are printed all along the table..